# html: Long picture links not working as hyperlinks

Tags: html

Look at the code snippet, somehow it actually works here but not on my website?

I have a piece of code that adds a nice picture to the forum, but when the link used by the user is too long, when you click on the picture it doesn't show the source picture

```
<a href="pictureURL"><img border="0" alt="foto fout" src="pictureURL" width="70" height="70"></a>
```

It basically makes a picture that you can click on and it sends you to the source. But what's iconic, is when you use a really long link, it doesn't work anymore in my page. But when you right-click the hyperlinked picture and open in the new tab manually, it does work.

So I tried this next

```
<a href="pictureURL" target="_blank"><img border="0" alt="foto fout" src="pictureURL" width="70" height="70"></a>
```

It still doesn't work for long links like this one... (Hover over it to see it, I thought it was quite messy just putting it there)

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p>A shorter picture link! Note that it's clickable</p>
<a href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a9/9b/4e/a99b4edacb5c68689a9609e89dbeaf52.jpg"><img border="0" alt="foto fout" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a9/9b/4e/a99b4edacb5c68689a9609e89dbeaf52.jpg" width="70" height="70"></a>

<p>A really long picture link! Note that it's not clickable but it actually is</p>
  <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
  
  
    <img width="70" height="70" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUTExIVFhUXFxcYFxgYFhUXFxgXFxcXHRgYGBUYHSggGBolHRgYITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGxAQGy0mHyUtLTUtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAKgBKwMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAACAgMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAADBQIEAAEGBwj/xABBEAABAwIDBAgDBgQGAQUAAAABAAIRAyEEEjEFQVFhBhMicYGRofAysdEHI0JiweEUUoLxM0Nyc5KyohUWJFPS/8QAGwEAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwQBAgUABgf/xAAvEQADAAIBAwMBBwMFAAAAAAAAAQIDESEEEjEFQVEyEyJCYXGBsRQjwTORodHw/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDy4LcqKibprZ6Hu+AzankihyrNCI1Si80w4Up/v5zZCaURpVkET2Ty/PzWw1baYNtZ8LI7Gh3I6XuDPhY668VJJXLFgaj5bQR/afr+qws9+/BTot27BhqK1i21im1qskEmSIpouVFbTW8m+PcfJW0MzOgDx3c98cFJrUZtP3+6kKfv6qyQaZ9xftSuadPMLuJDR3mb+QPoubYx1R0uJNiSTwAmB4J50lJHV+J8QW+/FIhXdJM+zISedvu0eV9ZzVXUON8LXH7BKuz3ATryFyBfVSGDrNJAzNgkGHEAEROnesp4xzTIP4YPO838gjVdrVCajs0FzGstawgbuXzQuDHTYSjjMS1oPxNOkgOMATrqf2WVcbXmOsi5/C0euX05KtSxz2GxIhobA8Z+fotsxhdZ9xfvki0eICt3P5GP6zqEtd9a/VhGbSrgfFI/MB8x9Vbwu3AbPbHNtx4jUeqhRwT2sDw5pYbAiT2jJDSLEFQxGGBHacOW+/CHGd/LepVUvDDYfVOqxPi2/wAnz/I8FxIuOK0QuewuJfRPFs3aZv8A6TET43+XQ0KrXtDmmQfQ8CNxTEWqPW9B6hj6udeKXlf9ESFEhGIUCFdj1SCIUSEUhQIUAakEQokIpCiQuA1IIhQIRSFAhcBpAyFFEIUCFAKkaWltYuKFQqQWltBFETCkw3Q4RGC6sSTaUVoE/NCpiPe5GYeUW571xZM3P7/VFbp37uSExwkWj1RmsBNnDug+yrILLLb3XbI1a2dPxNubg8T4hayC02txk6kaAfTVTAmm0i+Vzmk8Ae031z+SwwYPhw7z5kqyDQjYoxz9+aKygfd1qk06a8ONt3iPkEZjPfKbaBXGpk0xsa8p46owo2H0hbZTM30/fXvV+nRELm9BN6KLKCOzDclbZSurDWKrs77TQi2zsjrqeUDtC7e/h4rzxwgkbwYPgvZmUJtoquJ6BYav2u2xxPacwi/gQR4rP6jqYi+1mB6p0yy33x59zyQX3K5hsGXDMSGt4kgSeA96L1nZv2ZYJph7qtU8C8NA5TTAPqux2d0bwtLtU8PRZGjhTbm/5kZvVBfUz7GUujf4jxXZfRp9Rhy0a1WdHNY4t1uQY101KtjoXiaTS9+FqZAJdYGGjWYJ+Vl7zTNuSI4qV1L+CH0qXufPDCSwMa0Bs3BaLujjusPCJ5oVenkJ7Tg0zctzA7okEE24HQ77hdB0x2e2jjajKdgHBwG4Z2tdEcJJ9Ej2lXsCBDhd0TkP5gd0i87iJnUBtNNbQpUuXpiDaMZtI8oI3ERYg+klE2Hi8tXLPZfb+rd3Hd4qpiCZMi5vu8wRYzxGqrkxca/qqd2ntB+lzVgyTkn2Z25CgQpYepnY14/EAfPVbIT/AJR9HWrlUvDAkKJCKQokKoOpAkKLgiuCgQuAUgRCgQikKBXAKQMhQIRCFAhQBpECtKRUVwForwt7vfP6KQv6IgIA5z8kIUAtR6DLzug+REfqoZjxVrDtsXETAPjpb1Kk5g6oIMdw8oC0OA/v+yJUOhi5Em/h8vmspU5UotKCBkxxPD3ZYwKxQpaC5v8A3VnEUW2I9n3KukHiGaw9YXa67DGaNZFw5pO8GbHUEi0yDOolhAMEG4I0cOLZ8eYuDF0CmxMcCXNBAd2TqCA5vCcpBE+CskMTOuUBpjKe6DPKQjNYZ7iRvvBsmYwjHloIDXbi2zTJkZmHSZ1ERwO6DcKW2PxSZncd88T8ua7YVWmZhsOYBjdwt5+9yu0aIG+VqjS4q1TpobZWrN/wu9YKSZ4OnIhbq4UhDdC/23OmLMNTd1ktItDcpFyDrBnX6J9haZiNRxC86wG0MVh8XT7Zr4erVYJcAS3rHCQS0AsIJJH4YFhw9C2ttGlRYaj3hrDJJuZAytERcl027wsLPDd9z9xFZu/fGhhhC0QRPHeST3q+0bhLffNcLS+0BlV4pYHC1cRVOkgU2xa+8ho3udlCfYfDbVf2n1cJR4NZTdUPc5zjA8J0V1ipLkVrLNPg6Sk6N/msdUlK9nbTdnGHxLAytEsc21OqB8Rpn+YC5brF9xAZuHdy/dWaaK7T5PFunWIzbRrEaANbu1FNoPqSPBc3Wp52E8JieR0nXfryvrKtbbpVqVZ7aw+9zHOf5nEl0zGjpnx3JdnOV5AlpNy2CWzvy/FHhwWli4hGXn/1GKKrSDHohFWcQ28zmG4jXxG7uKrz77lDKo6zo+6aDeRcPWf1V8hL+irZoO5VD6tZ+6aOCfxcwj6N6ZXf0eN/l/HAAtQyEchDcFLGakCVAhFIUCFUBSBFQKIQoOCgXpAyoFEKgQuF6QMrUKRWlwFoqA296e/kjbh4+/kqwKPSM237vohIQTCAK41l2t3FhJ8Wlx9QP+KqMKYUG9gu3hrm931s6FYJoA0EieDv+39vkrdChpZRwrIBJuDaPH9Por4EWV5QfHBrq0Y0gWiec+/NEpsvw4qyQCBpujhv4b7q4dIrsw4GvLvVmjSAUhSO8yj0aOp3AT33AA8z81DZbZa6q5O8zA9J7uH7I7qeZodvs13ePhd4tt3gqpTcTffv+qZbMkva03DjlO+ziBpyMHvCGwVcLfwAZTVylRUqFIdyZYfDzoJQ2wWTLo1hKMEJwcJLZCDRw/JOtnU5sVRszs2X3PDtv4XF0K9c0qYbToy8vNmmm7tCDvsQIg38E16NgbSwuUg9k5SO4AwXTvsZ3HuTL7SnPGLfSpVI6ykyk5pa1wlxcZ0kEBwMiIiV0nRXYbMNQbTpti08yTvJ3lZmbt3x52Rjd8t+Gjm6sbOo5KTW0s1yblzyN7jv4AeQCjQ6XubTbUrUqjWuMB7w6m0m+jspboCddBK6fpBsw1qcWDgRlkA753i1+HqkjtnVqjKVKo8ltJ2ZgLWktcBYteCDIgEXmyCmvxbCNbX3Uhzsrb9GsAxwgjK8BxmDYsc1zZB7xzHFdCwze0LnejvRqjhwera65ntG3GGgWFyukbTge/mrrkBWl4OF+1XY7X4YVwPvKThcb2PMFp49otI4X4leOBzgZEZgNbEEHUOBvHcvc/tKqxgKvM0x51WLyPo/sJ2NxLaLH5W2c59zlaJ00uZsJ3bgnMF/c59hPPg7qTQixFWXAZe2THZ7WZp0BEy4jdvO/cVLbGyqlIh5o1mU3QQalOoyCfw5nAAn5r6B2J0bw2GDadMMNQAnO4N614BGY2vALh53mb2ukOFaabs0vYYFRjnFzHscQHNymwMG0RcBVfUL4Jno98b5PE+hkdQ//cP/AFamLwibK2cKLatIXDK9dknU5KhYCfBgRK7PBauF/dR7b0ldvSwn8FMhDcEZyG4IjRo0gLgoEIrkMhUYvSBFQcEUhQcFAvSBOCgQilDK4XtAyFCEQqMLgDQuaiMWhTU2hCRmpB3G/veE02eJp1ZP8hnnm+k+QSyJJ92H7JlSMU7aXbzLzqe7ICB3qwRPRJjuJtoOXf8AVWa1Ww7ju1gx9Eqa/wDvqrbDLbcfnMn0CIhma+CzTqmbW7kxwQJi/G/kluHpk+f6J3hWQI92lSwxaZTtdWWtIYY3n0aL/wDYeShRpzygSeQ928UdzxYDQeG/h5DwQ2yjfOiFBp5eQTPBCHtcSey5pOp0IVSiYKb4ZgVWwOWuCbMOQY1Bu3gRxCYUKSPhsKCw8iI7yCD8h5K1QwRQmzOvN8mYakmuEowQVDD4YjcmVKmqNiGXJs8lx9MVdqYiodG1MgP+2xoI9B5ldpSkAFom2k6Lyn7Qq1XC7XqGmfjcHREgh7Q424zN+SZYfPiHMNam+Do0V3sb3ljADJ5uKyrWqbZpwleOUvhHYbdxxoNFZw7AIFQHc02zDuMTyk7r2MK5ryCCOMoGB2XTDS3K6CCCHvqPEERADyY/dJtl0nYar/DuJLIzUXEyTTGrSf5mEgdxad6o/kmUmte52wcBvlQq1lTokojnSVfvF+zTOH+1jaTWYVtMm76jT/SySfUt9UL7FtnDqa2IIu+plafy0wJI4S437lxn2kbYNfEOaPgZLR65rQbnj+Vet9C8CMPgsPQJh5p5zze453d8F3oj/TiX5gW+7K9exf2vgA6lnFqlM52O3ixkTwIsl22tosZhRXq2YxjarxOuSHMb3uf1Y5ymvWCq0SZAkEHswWm7TAG/ivJ/tA283G1qeAw7s1MVM1Z7ZyktkBrSLFjBJnQkt4IeOO+uPAZ25nX4t8GbFzOoMe4y6pNRx51XOef+y3im2TBzQAABAFgOAGgVPE6FbscaPW9JPZEz8JCwqDgiEKBRmaLQJ6FCM4IZCGwFIGoORChuUC9IEQoORXIblAtSBlRUyoqQDROpR5eO7zQOrnTf8+c8k4NGbwgPGW4Hv3fwXORGoKL2GSAIufHx4IppkNZxzOPh2R5S0+Sm7mrL2aWOUCA6OyePa0uST4qNEdpUo0STbS4nuTDDMA08fnI8lAkAaeyiUgY+iskHhIZUqcfOVeos09VUwl4G5NaNMRJkiYgfitPkLeY0mVzCN6D/AAjLv1Ph+HwE+fIKTGzp5fRDzXJN3SSeEnVGY7h5e9UMp4RNjExwoVWmQdb/AKHv4Ky2uG3NvmeSHdJLbBW9nQUnkNaOIzHxsPQA/wBSa4HEcVyb31a5loNNsANANzAAueFkbZ21XUfu6jXPOrSTAjQiTc++ISP9ZDevb5EL6anO/f4O/oPBR0n2PtOnVph4IbeCCQCHDd8vNNwi7T5RkZJc1pnhn2vMJ2mcsZv4enBOgLnuE25AjxSfZWFxXZa6tHaAhoJbli5BNRt+UeK6b7YNlvdjabwcrX0WNab3cx7+zbf943zHBUNi7FxDYPXeBiPMJLLaltG30nONMZYHD4+n2mOziT2S1wBv2Ykndqntar1tOm8scx7atPsus5pc4MeOYyvJkWMAouALgAD4/srWKpXDuBn33IDvaJt7rksxFloC6BSrSpsfCjaA6OW2r9n+Eq1RUhzO0HOY0jK6DMXHZHIcdyfbRwb6jqZZVNJ1MlwIAMgtgtIO7TyVmpVQjUhpPFW79nKdeDzH7Wtp1qQp0RWd97ndVy9jOG5WtBDdxkzxyjgh9ENi9RRBc2Kr7utdo/CzlaCeZ5J/tnYrauMbiKlxSpNFNpuM+ckujlI8Y4KT3QZC1ellKExvo+mf2rzV+wGrQdEpXiU9z2vvSvF4UwSCCPVNwzd6fJzqhO4KNRhFiCDzsmmBw7IzuuQ7ThEJg8BwuJRavT0N31Cl60cu5Dcm+OwjYJAggSlDlG9k9ypbQNyG5FKG5VYK0DchkIjlBygWtAioqZUVwvQ1/iRcASRqToqteq7kgU3GeW9W8QxjBJE7gJN0UQ7nSF5cXd/AKeHbUa6Whw8CJWdZwMDl7uiU6W+V2gaXJaoggibcQAPloE1pMpEQ0vDrXcW5Y7g2Utwzb/VXm0QpGZ8F2mxzQBIuAd2h96K02q4gCRbQW4k/qUuaJ1JRDW3D0UNFxgHv9j9lum9/FVKSvbNwhe4DdqUHLc45dMhvSGOBovdckx80xZg7gnh3hGo0wBYad6Nh4N7xz9+5XnM2e8tbr/YVq/ctYWgQI0+iI/Dte3K8aacfBSZWj8JPiAsdm1yj1K5aFu6tiN2H6qobTYCTwuY9Ve2f0qq0iKAY1wAkE5phxdDbHdB8IVmtWYT94ffNUMFhm9Y6oBYgNHc0k2HPMfIKJbh7lha7ck/3Fsh01muaFZ1jSLoaPhIqZZPeMovzPG1nZzRlGkpX0gxhBbLH9WS4F4a4sDmgENLgIBgzfgVX6M7epPlpeA4G7TY+Ruup1T2zpmVj1J1bKcKevcqlba1Jg7dRo7yB81Rq7bFQfd/Dxgwe7e49ynwC7aYxqwN/uVUxGMGg8f3S3EY1rf8AEqtpxrmexh73OcYYPVVv/cmz6d34mm4jcxr6jR3ZGnN3lWnFdeEVrJEeWOsMHPuZDePHu+qsvEmPYXH7Q+1HCM+CnWqn/S1g/wDIz6Lm8X9rVa4pYWm3m97n+jQ1HXSZPgBXV4vk73aNO/vwSeoFrYe2KlfD06tQND3gk5Zj4nAQCTuAU6j51WpilzCRt9K9wmVS4yo1nZWk8bFWyGgc1E4cRFvmi7Hpte4swOjgBaZvwi3etU8S4vs2WixIt43Poi42WANaCOaW/wAS+bOJ3cvRES3yPRPenQ8Y9r2WvI9yFze0KGR5EQDpw8EQVy2QDrYn6IlLFHfBbaQbjzKlToiMLxt68C6nSLjDRJTAbKBaBJz6ki4Q6Ra2oSDDTm8AjUsQGauB812iKTZRr7NcJgg/M+CXPC6SowO01tPMFIMX8bu8qGgNrgquUVNygqitHTOwlIfeOBbT/DJ7b+cRDRziVWqYyP8ACY1g4xLj3nWe+VPGYrrHT4AbgOSjToD5o6QmoKf/AKhU0dDhwIBCLTxTXWjIeH4T/wDlTqsHAID6TSNF2ju1oZU6bTugjXd/dFdSHH0lKKNZ2l5GnMcPfBXKZe4hrGlxdAaAJJLtABxUPgsmtbCzaSf09FlAZjAuTwuvZehvRGnhaTTUa1+IIl7yAcpP4WE6AaSNdU9w+IoOe8McwvaQ18RmDi3MGnnlMxwMpZ9SlwkZd+qSm1M7/c8dwXR/Ev8Aho1D/Q4D/k4Aeq7TY/RCtTaC4skwSJdY8D2dy7pYls7+2Wq8CuX1HLfCSRxmO2HiAJa1r76NcNPGPYS9jQwxUHVn+VwIO+4kXHNehoGLwjKjS17QR8uYO4pKuknzJWOurxa4OKZW3Ng8z9FMuGrnesJf0iL8NWNL8JAcwgXLTIvzBHyO9LKdUu+J3qk3uXpmnGNXPdL4Y7rPYTcg38VOrimQAyxMAD9e4apJUcPhYBmN5OgHEnglGK6T0MOD1QdXqEdp4LWg/lD3ENAnc2TpMq8S34RF6nyzqq+Mo4Wk51Rxc1uZ7ozGYuTlHBeSdNOnFPFub1WGDWsJ7biBUM7rTDd8fJdTt7pZS/8ATatJ9Z2Hx1RmV9IMFR2UyDRc4AimxzTvIcJvwXkMDctDD06194ys/VUq1A9wnSc07ii0niXSfkrVXphi6tg4U26Ets8jhnOg/wBMLlXK9s+dYaBx09+CYw4Y7/Arl6rK58lynck6k6k3PfP6lEe7vVqnhnkdlmbuGY+sn0Rm7FxThbC4gjlRqn5NWn3Sl5Mpy296Yle3jAVSqzgLc10p6OYuJ/hao72HN5bkk2lgqlMxVp1WE6Z2OZfkHASgZKl+GMRFrymemdHGluEoA/8A1tPnf9VbcobPwraVJlNk5WtAEmTzJPGZUyhI+gdNPbjlP2SJS3jf9lunOp/dBqQEJlW9l2hpRtcEsWBeIkxrp6b0px1Esi4IPC3mEfaD3TIPZPu/1S4hGiWkP9PjaW9hMPhXPmItx+SMyk5pghotG4m9hAHuyjTe/LDd5MwBwaj0a2SG79558B9VPJNuuSiMKWkk3A7xPndDrVml0kGNw97k12k3MAI1Ou8JFVHlxUb4BKtzsO7GZXSwCIGs+9UvquJJJ1Jk+Km5DKq2BsEVFTcoSoFaHuEbmJPM24Ky6e/379FaotAdEDxAnzhXMl4siuhXehIaF53c1GpS3jTknOIpBxiPmqeIpiwE+YUqidip9OCCO49xK7b7NMXQo4mKre26G0nRIaXGPAumJ+q5qhhpN1Kq803hzZzQCDwIIg+ii13LQLLjWSHPyfQwIK4TCdATRxdKrSNIU2VhVdLaxquy0H0h94akEnMJERIni0tOjO3Ri6DX1QKVUyBlcbgGA4cjrBlKdo9On4KrVZiWCpTp3zss/LlBnKey4307Pisyl2vTPMVjqW0/Y75YlfR/pDhsbT6zDVm1G74s5p4PYbtPeE0XAzFixYVxx4p9t23X08dh6FFrnP6kuIbJJzPMAAAkwGOPiuS2dtDGVGdYTSp0phz3GA0c3nsl/wCRud/5Vf8AtH2xQdtHEVA/rz2KTWAubQa2m2CKpBBrHPmOQQ0Tcuu0cbisXVrubnc57rNY0CwBsGU6bRDRwa0BUcRT8Gn00Zu36tSdLitvNjqaZfiHOcALOpsc4kZQQIq1jNh/hj8ip7d2p/Cg02Oa7FficwNbTw/FtJrRBq7jU3bjvMsbhnbNolz4GLqtLaYBBNAGziTuq/ELfDlImTZHs7Z7GsFasMwdORkkGsQblzhdtIGxIu4ggRBLZmJe9eP5IzZKdLHi5b9yOzNhvq0xUfUZRpEn72oT2iDcMY0F9UibwIG8hM6Wzdns1dicQeXV4ame4nrHnyCpYjEPquzPMmABAADWjRrWizWgaAWWsh4ovLGun9MxpbvbGtPEYdh+7wOH5db1tdw/5vDf/FFf0mrt+B9Nm4CnQw7IHAFrJ9UiPegmpvHmdPDiVZYu4J1GXpOmn6Fv48sev6RYoiXYrERwFV7W+QICXVNp5j2s7u90/Mpe95OpJ71tlOUzPTwY9+tZF9Eyv22Wxj+FMcjIHyVmhtiq0OBlzXasJz0zyfScII52I3FUqdJThX/poa0LZPWuqvimtfoj0DY20mYikHstHZLS4S0jdcyeR3+asuK85weLfRf1jDB0I3OHBw4c9y7bZ20W1mB7bbiDq128FUqO16PT+kepT1S7K4pe3z+hbJ197whhtpB5RH6rHuQa86t77Lkj0Mz7EX6GXAiYg2IndzHNUKjQNDvTB4OW9jN/D2EsciSNY/c2yo4AwYG9SZVvmdfvKE5xWgOA71JLRexmJgNgkAifP2UvfizlLYEHlpzEWCkTNvD3zQKtKDxHFVaAVOuADkNyI4KDlUWsEQoIhQ1wvR6JRwwgGPErKwiyuhhaIGvoq9WlIVdiHcLqzpBym4hVazu0rbqIHnNuAVGo3tH0RUXQWm+NyDthnba3gxs+Mn9Qrez6IfUDdGi7juAFySh4sdbUfUbo4w2YFhYCTaQAAu9yN8lb+NrU2wyo4AaCQQN9gZjjZT+1V5AaC+TVbRJIOrerb5g5ZWqtFzYLmmIBEgiRxCQ9MqxcaI/laRc3yT2Ae7tDRUyY+7TMz1SdYe9e3+Tndnvq0XCrRqvpvGj2PLXDxG7kvXuhX2u1GxS2gM7dOvYO0P8Acpt+LvZf8p1XkAEmyttMbwp+xmvJ5h5nJ9b4TEsqsbUpva9jgC1zSC1wOhBGoXP/AGkbY/hdnYioHFr3M6umQYOep2QRzEl39K8N6A9Pauza7WPJOEqO+8YZOSf82nwI1IHxDnBXW/bNj6uKxlHAUGl5YM5a2L1Hi08A1l5MAB5lI3Ha9Gj0yWSl8e55RhsO57msY0uc4hrWtEkk6AAaldds1lLBl/aBqUmzia7CD1INhh8K4a13Xa6qPhAdlNi4rcbi6eEY6hhnipiHAtrYhh7LWx2qWGOuWJDqn4rgdnU2E2HnFOhUOWjSaMTi3XGUvb92x0XkMLQGC7nVXARdzaNfHuaObK7XHj+RdQb/ABTqmNxLYw7Dkp0mmA9wHYw7CIhjWwXuFw3m5qrYnEOqOLnGSfAADQACwaBYAWAEK7t/aYrPApsFKjTGSjSboxkzfi9x7Tnbye5C2Xs19UuiA1rcz3uMMpt/mceE2AEkmAASiTOkM9Ng+ynuvz7lUOhY6d6tYk0wRkByiwLvif8AmImG8mjQbybpfjapsN5v8xPd+6ZmONsN1GdY8TpkS6e758vfJQN1jFMVCNCR4wjpHkMt1kp1T5MZTPA+SuUqa1hy4j4nR3lXWMhFlCdvbAinzUXshW8oA0Qi3dxViqRRqBWNh47qawk9h/Zd3/hd4H0JQawVGuUHJyhvpc1Yck5J8o9Iq1BE8EGnjKe97RyJHylC2bU6yg1x3tv3gQVPZ9MDQAIcraPo2TqqeObx+KWzMTjaRaQKjfMeqUVscwaEHuITzFkwuWxr8rg4QYMwrrhAV1uaPxcfoho8LdF5BkTv0QcPiA4CWODoBmQWmeG8W5q4ymSCN2sDiPfqu8m1OWck9y/5I0XmTBgbwbz5C+qrVSRofJWurgkd44+zuVN7jqufg6iuUJyO4TPn6oBQxW2QcowplRXaF6PUamLbNwR4oVbEWsPfetLFXRnqUhZiK4aDxSx5c49kW3ncPFYsRpWlsuTOIEChTcBm/wASodI1I7reOm9dQ2k3I1rWAUw0AA/GfzPP4SbnKON+A2sQ7BWvcVOaGg2dAcezMgwZaS2YJiFwfSvEB+JeWtygANAiNBJsNLkrFileTK9ZprDK+X/gW4WnJVrEMIFxI5SD6hbWJiV908tT+8Iq7m5tCWzJabTxEjjpK7zb223VqlShhM1SriHH+IrNBDq5P+VTBvTwzQIgntBsusFixZl+Wzd6SV2tlvov0afR++rdUIGcNcWPZ2bddVdBy0aZJGVpJqPhokCyXb+1muHUUM3Utc55c7/Er1XfFXq8XG8D8IMDUk4sQpe+WaPSQqbt+dlHY+zX4iq2lTiXakmGtaLue87mtAJJ4BM9r7UYQMNh5GFpmZNnYioP86py/lZ+EcyVtYj4luuRr6sun4S3+4grVLknuH6qFau55GY/C0NbYCGiYFhzJnfJWLE2kYPX57vI5fgg15BtbuVzDVHn8RPff1K2sRJMqm2xjSZbw4DxU3thYsVzqS0QbZRe0xO70WLFWiInYuxBVCvoVixDrwTK5Ov6OVv/AI4HM/p9U0wDbLaxVn6T3mJ66LC/yCY6kQNNy4raDzmNltYrP6RfLTaL4e/7vKQOwN3CNwIlOcO6sW/4o/4fVyxYu9hzOvvfsv4Qu2nTqDV4P9H7pbs8kudJ0G7n/ZYsUteCMC/ux/72L8WJ8PP9pVZ6xYqM1MgMqMrFigWZ/9k="/>
  
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Comment: I don't think you can navigate to a 'data url'.

Comment: you can add onclick event on your img, <img src="pictureURL" onclick="location='pictureURL'">.

Comment: @CristianV     It still doesn't work for the pictures with the long urls :(

Comment: what do you expect to display at the hover? At the hover is displayed the huge link. If i click on the image it is displayed. I test on Mozilla browser.

Comment: @CristianV I edited the snippet and realised it actually works here, I suppose my website is cursed, I should probably close this question

Comment: Going off what @RamRamesh-Kithsiri-HettiArachchi said, your data uri may be adding the server information on top of the data uri to make it too long. When you click on it, it becomes `https://your.web.site/path/to/your/page/data:image/jpeg;base64....` making it to long